# Spring Cloud Consul health check configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul

I'm running a Spring Boot application as a Docker container. This works fine so far, but it's giving me some head aches when trying to use Spring Cloud Consul as well. It reads the configuration from the Consul KVS just fine, but the health checks seem to be acting up.

The default health check uses the hostname of the docker container, for example http://users-microservice/health. Obviously this won't resolve when accessed from Consul.

No problem, the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/) mentions that you can use *healthCheckPath* in your bootstrap.yml file to configure it. This is what I have now:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: users-microservice
    cloud:
        consul:
        host: myserver.com
        port: 8500
        config:
            prefix: API-CONFIG
            profileSeparator: '__'
        discovery:
            tags: users-microservice
            healthCheckPath: http://myserver.com:${server.port}/status
            healthCheckInterval: 30s
```

Unfortunately, this variable seems to be used in a very different manner from what I expected. This is what Consul is trying to reach:

`Get http://users:18090http//myserver.com:18090/status: dial tcp: unknown port tcp/18090http`

How can I fix this? Is there some undocumented configuration parameter that I should set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.healthCheckUrl=http://myserver.com:${server.port}/status`

`healthCheckPath` only changes the path, not host and port.